# Strange symbol appearing in HTML on android - phonegap app

Tags: android, css, cordova

I'm creating a mobile app with backbone, phonegap and for css topcoat (http://topcoat.io/).

I have a strange problem when viewing the app on my android phone. Im using android version 2.3.3. A mail symbol on it's side appears, seemingly whereever p and span tags are used.

[image]

Here is the code (in this case it goes into the else):

```
<ul class="topcoat-list list">
<% _.each(players, function(player) { %>
    <li class="topcoat-list__item">

        <%
        if(checkbox){
        %>

        <label class="topcoat-radio-button">
          <input type="radio" name='player_id' value="<%= player.id %>" />
          <div class="topcoat-radio-button__checkmark"></div>
            <div class="player-details">
                <span><%= player.name %></span>
                <span><%= player.position %></span>
           </div>   
        </label>
        <%
        }
        else{
        %>
            <div class="player-details">
                <span><%= player.name %></span>
                <span><%= player.position %></span>
            </div>   
        <%
        }
        %>
            <div class="player-more">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://www.premierleague.com/<%= player.link %>">More</a>
            </div>            



    </li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
```

I have gone through topcoat.io css but it doesn't set any css for span or p tags...Any ideas what could be producing this weird symbol?

Comment: What editor are you using to write your HTML?  Is it on Windows?

Comment: This is an encode issue

Comment: Do you have `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in the `<head>` section?

Comment: @JasonSperske I use netbeans and its on linux

Comment: @MBillau Yes i do, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

This is an encode issues. Where is the code that generates this HTML. It could be the linebreak code causing it. Remove the line break.

```
<li class="topcoat-list__item">
        <div class="player-details">
            <span>Tim Krul</span><span>Goalkeeper</span>
        </div>   
        <div class="player-more">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.premierleague.com//en-gb/players/profile.overview.html/tim-krul">More</a>
        </div>              
</li>
```

Comment: I edited the code to show the underscore.js that generates the html (i hadn't realised that could be the problem)