# Unicode Symbols on Android with Phonegap

Tags: android, html, cordova, character-encoding, phonegap-build

I'm new to the mobile development world and I'm trying to do my first app using **Phonegap**.

When I try to use Unicode it doesn't work on Android.
I've already tried to set **UTF-8** and also **ISO-8859-1** but it didn't change nothing.

This is the simbol in the green button. `&#9708;`

Here is the header of my *index*.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Feices</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    scrollTo(0,1);
    </script>
</head>
```

And the header of *my config.xml*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

As I don't have enough reputation to post images, so I've uploaded the screenshots in imgur.

App running on my computer, using Ripple extension in Chrome.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi4It.png

App running on my cellphone, using Phonegap app to run the application. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd1sP.jpg

Is there any way to make these characters work on Android? (Considering that I'm going to use hundreds of them and some workdaround woulnd't)

Good day :)

Comment: It seems [here someone has the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833728).

Comment: @Xufox I've already looked at this one and sadly this didn't solve my problem. :(

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Comment: sadly no, @HiramHibbard